# Cannot declare variable inside @interface or @protocol, moving cause crash elsewhere

Tags: ios, xcode

Thanks for reading, the following code worked absolutely fine on previous versions of Xcode and iOS

I upgraded to the latest Xcode and now the line  NSInteger userID;  is giving the error.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <sqlite3.h>
@class IWalletUser;
@class IWCard;
@class IWCardObject;
@class IWVault;
@class IWWallet;

@interface IWDatabaseController : UIViewController {
}
NSInteger userID;


//+(BOOL) execSQL:(char*)sql;
+(BOOL)InserOrUpdateQueryWhereQueryIs:(char*)query;
+ (BOOL) getInitialData;
+ (void) finalizeStatements;
+(int)addUser:(NSString *)theUserName  password:(NSString *)thePassword loginPassword:(NSString*)_loginPassword isFirstTime:(BOOL)isFirstTime usePattern:(BOOL)usePattern;
+(void)updateUser:(NSString *)theUserName userID:(int)_userID password:(NSString *)thePassword loginPassword:(NSString*)_loginPassword isFirstTime:(BOOL)isFirstTime usePattern:(BOOL)usePattern;

+(int)addWallet:(id)walletName forUser:(int)uID categoryID:(int)categoryID vault:(id)vault;
+(void)renameWallet:(IWWallet*)wallet categoryID:(int)categoryID vault:(id)vault;
```

If I move the line    NSInteger userID;   to before  @interface  then the app compiles Ok, but when I run the app it crashes elsewhere which it never did before so I am guessing it is because the userID cannot be resolved.

Any help appreciated, thanks

Comment: define it using `@property()`

Answer (score 1):

If you are declaring an instance variable, put it between the { } for your @interface.